# Compute the value of the modulo without using a calculator

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Compute the value without using a calculator:

$1\times2\times3\times\cdots\times89\times90\times91 \bmod 29$. This is the product of all numbers from $1$ to $91$.

I'm not sure how to do this without a calculator when there are so many numbers to compute.

Comment: Is not $29$ a factor of the product?

Comment: Doing it _with_ a calculator may be more challenging than without. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the numbers in the range from $1$ to $91$ is $29$.  If you multiply any whole number at all by $29$ and then reduce modulo $29$, you always get the *same* answer.

Comment: Ah, my question sounds silly now that I understand why this is. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

29 is one of the numbers in 1 ... 91